# How can I re-use a flowtype type definition on a class and its defaults without duplicating the type specification?

Tags: javascript, flowtype

Example of what I'm trying to do:

```
//@flow

interface MyLibDefaults {
  foo: string,
  bar: boolean
};

class MyLib implements MyLibDefaults {

  defaults: MyLibDefaults;

  // do I really have to put these type specifications again? There are a lot of them....
  foo: string;
  bar: false;


  constructor() {
    this.defaults = {
      foo: "",
      bar: false
    };

    Object.assign(this, defaults);
  }

  ///...
  resetToDefaults() {
    Object.assign(this, defaults);
  }
}
```

Maybe the interface isn't the right approach, but I can't figure out how to have my class "`extend`" the type definition with its own defaults.

Answer (score 0):

From Flow's docs:

> Flow also supports using the [class properties syntax](https://tc39.github.io/proposal-class-public-fields/) (...) When using this syntax, you are not required to give it a type annotation. But you still can if you need to.

So you can do:

```
//@flow

interface MyLibDefaults {
  foo: string,
  bar: boolean
};

class MyLib implements MyLibDefaults {

  defaults: MyLibDefaults;
  foo = "";
  bar = false;

  constructor() {
    this.defaults = {
      foo: this.foo,
      bar: this.bar,
    };
  }

  ///...
  resetToDefaults() {
    Object.assign(this, this.defaults);
  }
}
```

Of course, you'll need to [enable class properties syntax in Babel](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-class-properties/).